# Sensor Diagnostic Tool in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8

Where can i find the Sensor Diagnostic tool for Windows 8 so that i can check what are the sensors supported in my current PC?

Comment: Searching settings for `Sensor` on my desktop I get Location settings. Do you get any more on a machine with more sensors?

Comment: Google search returned [this](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Info/Motherboard-Monitor.shtml) and [this](http://www.hmonitor.com/) not sure if they are compatible in W8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wdk/thread/9168c07c-a7fa-4fce-81a2-4c34490b3729) it is part of the [Windows Driver Kit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg487428.aspx) (WDK).

Answer (score 2):

Its a part of WDK and when you run the tool it checks for Sensors.Sensors are supported at most for the Latest Laptops and Ultrabook..

The Details can be found [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wdk/thread/9168c07c-a7fa-4fce-81a2-4c34490b3729).

For more Details you can find an Article at Intel Developer Zone [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wdk/thread/9168c07c-a7fa-4fce-81a2-4c34490b3729)